# morse code to english python3

Tags: python, dictionary, morse-code

i want to convert Morse Code to English using Python 3+
I have managed to convert english to morse code using this 
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578407-simple-morse-code-translator-in-python/

But i want to convert Morse Code to English

I have attempted to do it one charecter at a time, but the problem is that morse code letters are not 1 charecter long like english letters, so E is "." and S is "...", the problem i have is that the dictionary loop will find the "." and match it to E, so instead of getting S i get "E E E"
i tried to fix this by detecting spaces and doing it a word at a time, but instead of looking for the letters in the word it searches the entire word against the dictionary
i'm new to Python and dictionaries and i don't know how to differeniate between an E "." and an S "..." when searching my dictionary

Here is my code

```
# defines the dictionary to convert morse to english
CODE_reversed = {'..-.': 'F', '-..-': 'X',
                 '.--.': 'P', '-': 'T', '..---': '2',
                 '....-': '4', '-----': '0', '--...': '7',
                 '...-': 'V', '-.-.': 'C', '.': 'E', '.---': 'J',
                 '---': 'O', '-.-': 'K', '----.': '9', '..': 'I',
                 '.-..': 'L', '.....': '5', '...--': '3', '-.--': 'Y',
                 '-....': '6', '.--': 'W', '....': 'H', '-.': 'N', '.-.': 'R',
                 '-...': 'B', '---..': '8', '--..': 'Z', '-..': 'D', '--.-': 'Q',
                 '--.': 'G', '--': 'M', '..-': 'U', '.-': 'A', '...': 'S', '.----': '1'}


    def main():
        #takes user message and makes it upper case
        msg = input('MESSAGE: ')
        msg = msg.upper()

    addtolist = "" # creates blank string
    message = [] # creates blank list
    for i in msg:
        addtolist = addtolist + i # adds every letter in MSG into a string until it finds a space
        addtolist.upper() # makes every letter uppercase

        if i == " ": # if it detects a space
            message.extend(addtolist)
            # adds the previously created addtolist to a list, this makes one word
            addtolist = "" # clears previous variable

    for i in message:
        # for every word in the list
        str(i) # make it into a string
    print(CODE_reversed[i()]) # search the dictionary for that word


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This code takes a word, and tries to look it up against the dictionary, but it doesn't work
i have also tried searching each individual morse code letter against the dictionary but the problem is that you can't tell when a letter starts and ends, so "..." comes out as "EEE" instead of "S" and i don't know how to fix this

i have also tried searching for solutions but have only found them in Java and i do not know Java

Comment: You have to scan the input until you reach a pause indicating next character. For example if you have input `". . ."` there's space between the dots and you have three `"."`s, but if the input is `"..."` you have no space so you have one `"..."`. You can do this by using the `split` method on the input.

Comment: It's a mathematical problem that the code (Morse) is not an injective function. You have to know the spaces (breaks) between the code elements. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Once you define the mapping in one direction, you can use a dict comprehension to map it the other way

```
CODE = {'A': '.-',     'B': '-...',   'C': '-.-.', 
        'D': '-..',    'E': '.',      'F': '..-.',
        'G': '--.',    'H': '....',   'I': '..',
        'J': '.---',   'K': '-.-',    'L': '.-..',
        'M': '--',     'N': '-.',     'O': '---',
        'P': '.--.',   'Q': '--.-',   'R': '.-.',
        'S': '...',    'T': '-',      'U': '..-',
        'V': '...-',   'W': '.--',    'X': '-..-',
        'Y': '-.--',   'Z': '--..',

        '0': '-----',  '1': '.----',  '2': '..---',
        '3': '...--',  '4': '....-',  '5': '.....',
        '6': '-....',  '7': '--...',  '8': '---..',
        '9': '----.' 
        }

CODE_REVERSED = {value:key for key,value in CODE.items()}
```

Then you can use `join` with a generator expression to perform the translations.

```
def to_morse(s):
    return ' '.join(CODE.get(i.upper()) for i in s)

def from_morse(s):
    return ''.join(CODE_REVERSED.get(i) for i in s.split())

>>> to_morse('hello')
'.... . .-.. .-.. ---'
>>> from_morse('.... . .-.. .-.. ---')
'HELLO'
```

Comment: great example of python power

Comment: thank you!  i knew there was an easier way to do this, python truly is amazing!

Answer (score 0):

```
 mor = {'.-': 'A',   '-...': 'B',   '-.-.': 'C',
       '-..': 'D',      '.': 'E',   '..-.': 'F',
         -.': 'G',   '....': 'H',     '..': 'I',  
      '.---': 'J',    '-.-': 'K',   '.-..': 'L',
        '--': 'M',     '-.': 'N',    '---': 'O', 
      '.--.': 'P',   '--.-': 'Q',    '.-.': 'R',
       '...': 'S',      '-': 'T',    '..-': 'U', 
      '...-': 'V',    '.--': 'W',   '-..-': 'X',
      '-.--': 'Y',   '--..': 'Z',  '-----': '0', 
     '.----': '1',  '..---': '2',  '...--': '3',
     '....-': '4',  '.....': '5',  '-....': '6', 
     '--...': '7',  '---..': '8',  '----.': '9'}
print('''Enter your msg in Morse.
Notic that: 
    1- Use / to separate the letters and space to separate words.
    2- Your message must contain only letters and numbers.
    3- '?' in output means that your input was unknowed.
    >>> ''', end = '')
msg = input(' ')              
out = []
letter = []
j = -1
for i in msg.split(' '):
    j += 1
    letter += [i.split('/')]
    for k in range(len(letter[j])):
        out += mor.get(letter[j][k], '?')
    out += ' '
print('\n      >>> Your msg is: ', end = '')
print(''.join(out))`
```

output:

```
Enter your msg in Morse.

Notic that: 

      1- Use / to separate the letters and space to separate words.
      2- Your message must contain only letters and numbers.
      3- '?' in output means that your input was unknowed.
      >>> ...././.-../.-.. .--/---/.-./.-../-.. (for example)

      >>> Your msg is: HELLO WORLD
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but in the tradition of open source I wrote code to implement the fact that Morse is a binary tree and this may be faster than using a dictionary:

```
class node:
    def __init__(self, char):
        self.dot = None
        self.dash = None
        self.alpha = char

    def __str__(self):
        return self.alpha

    def nextNode(self, basenode, char):
        if char == '.' and basenode.dot is None:
            basenode.dot = node('*')
            return basenode.dot
        elif char == '.':
            return basenode.dot
        elif char == '-' and basenode.dash is None:
            basenode.dash = node('*')
            return basenode.dash
        elif char == '-':
            return basenode.dash
        else:
            return basenode

    def traverse(self, basenode, tone):
        current = basenode
        for char in tone:
            current = self.nextNode(current, char)
        return current

    def insert(self, basenode, key):  # @  val = tuple ('P','.--.')
        char = self.traverse(basenode, key[1])
        char.alpha = key[0]

    def decode(self, basenode, tone):  #@  tone is a morse string
        return self.traverse(basenode, tone).alpha


class morse:
    def __init__(self, char):
        self.base = node(char)
        self.MORSE = {'A': '.-', 'B': '-...',
                           'C': '-.-.', 'D': '-..', 'E': '.',
                           'F': '..-.', 'G': '--.', 'H': '....',
                           'I': '..', 'J': '.---', 'K': '-.-',
                           'L': '.-..', 'M': '--', 'N': '-.',
                           'O': '---', 'P': '.--.', 'Q': '--.-',
                           'R': '.-.', 'S': '...', 'T': '-',
                           'U': '..-', 'V': '...-', 'W': '.--',
                           'X': '-..-', 'Y': '-.--', 'Z': '--..',
                           '1': '.----', '2': '..---', '3': '...--',
                           '4': '....-', '5': '.....', '6': '-....',
                           '7': '--...', '8': '---..', '9': '----.',
                           '0': '-----', ', ': '--..--', '.': '.-.-.-',
                           '?': '..--..', '/': '-..-.', '-': '-....-',
                           '(': '-.--.', ')': '-.--.-', ' ': ' '}
        for x in self.MORSE:
            self.base.insert(self.base, (x, self.MORSE.get(x)))

    def translate(self, tone):
        return self.base.decode(self.base, tone)

    def __str__(self):
        print(self.base)
        return

y = morse(' ')
code = ["-.-.", '.-.', '-.--', '.-.-.-', ' ', '--', '.', '.-.-.-', ' ', '.-',
        '.-.-.-', ' ', '.-.', '..', '...-', '.', '.-.', '.-.-.-']
line =[]
for char in code:
    line.append(y.translate(char))
print(*line)
```

this could likely be much more efficient if for instance the dictionary was presorted into the correct order starting with 'E' & 'T' then we would not have to  build the tree the way I did. and I am very new to python so likely there are other ways to do this, but this works.  I plan to add a function that can listen to live code and translate.