# morse code to english-looping over entire morse letter before returning instead of returning each dot or dash

Tags: python

I am trying to convert from English to morse which I have already done. Also, I have to reverse the morse code I got and then convert that into English. I believe my for loop is what is the problem because it returns each dot/dashes English letter. My morse code output prints each morse character with 4 spaces between each character.

```
def decodeMorsetoChar(rev_morse):
  splitt=rev_morse[::-1]
  
  splitt=list(rev_morse)
  lengthh=len(splitt)
  listt=''
  for code in range(0, lengthh):
    char = splitt[code]
    

    if char== ".-" :
      char = "A"
    elif char== "-..." :
      char = "B"
    elif char== "-.-." :
      char = "C"
    elif char== "-.." :
      char = "D"
    elif char== ".":
      char = "E"
    elif char== "..-." :
      char = "F"
    elif char== "--.":
      char = "G"
    elif char== "...." :
      char = "H"
    elif char== ".." :
      char = "I"
    elif char== ".---" :
      char = "J"
    elif char== "-.-":
      char = "K"
    elif char== ".-..":
      char = "L"
    elif char== "--" :
      char = "M"
    elif char== "-.":
      char = "N"
    elif char== "---":
      char = "O"
    elif char== ".--.":
      char = "P"
    elif char== " --.-":
      char = "Q"
    elif char== ".-.":
      char = "R"
    elif char== "..." :
      char = "S"
    elif char== "-":
      char = "T"
    elif char== "..-":
      char = "U"
    elif char== "...-":
      char = "V"
    elif char== ".--" :
      char = "W"
    elif char== "-..-" :
      char = "X"
    elif char== "-.--":
      char = "Y"
    elif char== "--.." :
      char = "Z"
 
    listt=listt + '' + char

  return listt

decodeMorsetoChar("--.- ..- .. -")
```

This currently returns "TTET EET EE T", but I would like it to return: "QUIT"

Comment: You need to at least include some sample input if you want people to debug your code for you.  :)  It seems like this code might work provided that the input is formatted correctly as a list of Morse code characters -- but are you maybe giving it a string instead of a list?  Converting it to a list with `list` is going to split the Morse characters up so you just get a bunch of Es and Ts at the end.

Comment: check the edit, I have included a sample input

Comment: Please put it in the code (fill in the blank: `decodeMorseToChar(...)`), along with the output you get from that input, and what output you want it to have instead.  It's still not clear to me whether your sample input is a single string or a list.

Comment: Your last edit makes your code invalid.

Comment: You got some answers... could you give some feedback?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you look at the input one character at a time. `char` is always just one character:

```
for code in range(0, lengthh):
  char = splitt[code]
```

Instead make your loop on the *words* in the input. You can get those words with `rev_morse.split()`, and so you could make your loop:

```
for char in rev_morse.split():
```

...and then continue with the lookup of that "char". With this change you don't need the `splitt` and `lengthh` variables.

Now, apparently the morse letters come in reversed order, so undo that reversal:

```
for char in reversed(rev_morse.split()):
```

This change will make it work. You can then improve and use a dictionary for lookup instead of this long `if..elif` block.

[This answer to a morse question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32094652/5459839) provides simple encoding and decoding functions.

Comment: thank you,that makes sense but do you know why I get --.- UIT as the output for input tidy. For every thing else it converts the first morse character to english just this one doesnt

Comment: That is because you have a space dangling in your `if` structure where the result should be "Q". It has `elif char== " --.-":` instead of `elif char== "--.-":` (one space removed)

Comment: Did this solve your issue? Can you give some feed-back?

Answer (score 0):

Use `split()` on `rev_morse[::-1]` to break your single string into a list of characters that you can look up the code for.  You can make it more compact by putting the morse code characters into a dict instead of having a long chain of `if/elif`:

```
def decode_reverse_morse(rev_morse: str) -> str:
    """Translates reversed Morse code."""
    morse_code = {
        ".-": "A",
        "-...": "B",
        "-.-.": "C",
        "-..": "D",
        ".": "E",
        "..-.": "F",
        "--.": "G",
        "....": "H",
        "..": "I",
        ".---": "J",
        "-.-": "K",
        ".-..": "L",
        "--": "M",
        "-.": "N",
        "---": "O",
        ".--.": "P",
        " --.-": "Q",
        ".-.": "R",
        "...": "S",
        "-": "T",
        "..-": "U",
        "...-": "V",
        ".--": "W",
        "-..-": "X",
        "-.--": "Y",
        "--..": "Z",
    }
    return ''.join(
        morse_code.get(char, char)
        for char in rev_morse[::-1].split()
    )


print(decode_reverse_morse("--- ..-. ..-. . ...."))  # HELLO
```

You could also separate decoding the Morse code from reversing the string, like this:

```
def decode_morse(morse: str) -> str:
    """Translates Morse code."""
    morse_code = {
        ".-": "A",
        "-...": "B",
        "-.-.": "C",
        "-..": "D",
        ".": "E",
        "..-.": "F",
        "--.": "G",
        "....": "H",
        "..": "I",
        ".---": "J",
        "-.-": "K",
        ".-..": "L",
        "--": "M",
        "-.": "N",
        "---": "O",
        ".--.": "P",
        " --.-": "Q",
        ".-.": "R",
        "...": "S",
        "-": "T",
        "..-": "U",
        "...-": "V",
        ".--": "W",
        "-..-": "X",
        "-.--": "Y",
        "--..": "Z",
    }
    return ''.join(
        morse_code.get(char, char)
        for char in morse.split()
    )


def decode_reverse_morse(reverse_morse: str) -> str:
    """Translates reversed Morse code."""
    return decode_morse(reverse_morse[::-1])
```