# Remove extra space before word ends

Tags: python, dictionary

I need some help removing the extra space before a word/string ends. Does anyone have any ideas?

input:

`hello`

output I get (two spaces at the end):

```
' ....  .  .-..  .-..  ---  '
```

expected output (only one space at the end, but two spaces between letters):

```
' ....  .  .-..  .-..  --- '
```

Here's my code:

```
MORSE_CODES={'A':'.-','B':'-...','C':'-.-.',
'D':'-..','E':'.','F':'..-.','G':'--.',
'H':'....','I':'..','J':'.---','K':'-.-',
'L':'.-..','M':'--','N':'-.','O':'---',
'P':'.--.','Q':'--.-','R':'.-.',
'S':'...','T':'-','U':'..-','V':'...-',
'W':'.--','X':'-..-','Y':'-.--','Z':'--..'}


def encode_Morse(my_msg):
  my_msg=my_msg.upper()

  my_msg_Morse=" "
  for letter in my_msg:
    
    if letter!=" " and letter not in MORSE_CODES:
      my_msg_Morse+=" * "
    elif letter!=" ":
       my_msg_Morse+= MORSE_CODES[letter]+"  "
    else:
      my_msg_Morse+=" "

  return my_msg_Morse
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32094525/morse-code-to-english-python3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just do:

```
my_msg_Morse_list.replace(' ','')
```

**Edited**

I was corrected,
If the problem is always two spaces at the maybe you could just trim the string with

```
my_msg_Morse = my_msg_Morse[:-1]
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback, I edited my answer

Comment: where does this go?

Comment: just before the return in ```encode_Morse(my_msg)``` and outside the ```for ``` loop

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `split()` method on your string to parse out your morse code into an iterable and then iterate over each code, first using `strip()` and then ignoring empty elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this one of two ways:

1. Keep track of the index of every letter in your iteration using `enumerate()`. Check if this is the last letter in `my_msg`. If it is, don't add the second space.

```
def encode_Morse(my_msg):
  my_msg=my_msg.upper()

  my_msg_Morse=" "
  for index, letter in enumerate(my_msg):
    
    if letter!=" " and letter not in MORSE_CODES:
      my_msg_Morse+=" * "
    elif letter!=" ":
       my_msg_Morse+= MORSE_CODES[letter] + " "
       if index < len(my_msg) - 1:
           my_msg_Morse += " "
    else:
      my_msg_Morse+=" "

  return my_msg_Morse
```

2. Build a list and then use [`str.join()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_join.asp) to join it with spaces. We'll also have to add one space before and after the result of the `join()`.

```
def encode_Morse(my_msg):
  my_msg=my_msg.upper()

  my_msg_Morse_list = []
  for letter in my_msg:
    if letter=" " and letter not in MORSE_CODES:
      my_msg_Morse_list.append("*")
    elif letter!=" ":
       my_msg_Morse_list.append(MORSE_CODES[letter])
    else:
      my_msg_Morse_list.append(" ")
  # Add the leading and trailing space
  return " " + "  ".join(my_msg_Morse_list) + " "
```

I'm going to rewrite your function to make the if-else ladder a little more clear. First, I'm going to add a value for a space in the `MORSE_CODES` dictionary. This eliminates the need to check if `letter` is a space. Then, I'm going to use the [`dict.get()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_get.asp) function to get the value of the key `letter` from `MORSE_CODES`. `get()` lets us specify a default value to be returned if the given key doesn't exist in the dictionary.

```
MORSE_CODES={'A':'.-','B':'-...','C':'-.-.',
'D':'-..','E':'.','F':'..-.','G':'--.',
'H':'....','I':'..','J':'.---','K':'-.-',
'L':'.-..','M':'--','N':'-.','O':'---',
'P':'.--.','Q':'--.-','R':'.-.',
'S':'...','T':'-','U':'..-','V':'...-',
'W':'.--','X':'-..-','Y':'-.--','Z':'--..', ' ': ' '}

def encode_Morse(my_msg):
  my_msg=my_msg.upper()
  my_msg_Morse_list = []
  for letter in my_msg:
    morse_letter = MORSE_CODES.get(letter, "*")
    my_msg_Morse_list.append(morse_letter)

  # Add the leading and trailing space
  return " " + "  ".join(my_msg_Morse_list) + " "
```

When you do all these things, you can write your entire function in one line if you'd like using a generator expression in place of the loop:

```
def encode_Morse(my_msg):
  return " " + "  ".join(MORSE_CODES.get(letter, "*") for letter in my_msg.upper()) + " "
```

For every function, you can check that it gives the expected output by checking that the following code  gives `True`

```
' ....  .  .-..  .-..  --- ' == encode_Morse("hello")
```

Comment: why would I have to create a list ?

Comment: So that you can use `str.join()` to join all elements of the list with two spaces between them `"  ".join(["a", "b"])` gives you `"a  b"`

Comment: can you add another elif statement that could say not to put a space after the last letter in a string?

Comment: Your question says you want _one_ space after the last letter. What do you actually want?

Comment: I need two spaces between morse letters and one space after the last morse character.

Comment: That is what all the functions I have given you do. What do you want to _"add another elif statement that could say not to put a space after the last letter in a string"_ for? And which function are you referring to when you say that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231140/discussion-between-pranav-hosangadi-and-qwvst).